# cannot see enable evergreen function development in salesforce dev hub

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, dev-hub, function, development-mode

We want to **Enable Evergreen Function Development** in the salesforce dev hub, But not able to find the enable option

[image]

Please assist.

Comment: I think it's still in Limited Developer Preview. Have you contacted your AC to enroll in Preview?

Comment: Hi @ytiq
This my developer edition box

Comment: ye, it's still is closed Beta, therefor you don't access to it